# How to create an Attribute value for range condition in DynamoDB for GSI

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I want to search the GSI in my DynamoDB. However I would like to search with KeyConditionExpression. In this case I won't be able to search by  RangeKeyCondition as I get an error: `The range key conditions can only be specified when the key condition expression is not specified.`

I think the way to go about this is using withExpressionAttributeValues, but I am not sure how to use it for a range condition. I have not been to find any examples.

Comment: Can you show your code and include key attribute info of GSI?

Answer (score 0):

AWS documentation has a full blown example of how to use [KeyConditionExpression here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryingJavaDocumentAPI.html#DocumentAPIJavaQueryExample). You would need to specify an index name and use an Index instead of a Table object.

```
DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(
    new AmazonDynamoDBClient(new ProfileCredentialsProvider()));
Index index = dynamoDB.getTable("Reply").getIndex("IndexName");
QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec()
    .withKeyConditionExpression("Id = :v_id")
    .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
        .withString(":v_id", "Amazon DynamoDB#DynamoDB Thread 1"));
ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = index.query(spec);
```